# Field data isn't lined up in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Any idea why the data won't line up?

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48zLE.png)

Comment: the insert query is at the top of the picture

Comment: The fields line up just fine.  You are just confused at the difference between `insert` and `update`.

Comment: If I select a field individually, there is about 10 lines of empty space for say last_name,  which I don't want and don't know how to fix

Comment: There is no insert query anywhere in that picture

Comment: Select is NOT an `INSERT` query. It looks "as-if" you inserted first names, then inserted last names, then address, etc. What you have IS fixable by doing `UPDATE` queries. (or you could, of course, start over if not too unreasonable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't "line up" because it's been inserted as different records. If you have a person called John Smith, age 40, from Canada, you appear to have done this:

```
INSERT INTO person(firstname) VALUES('john');
INSERT INTO person(lastname) VALUES('smith');
INSERT INTO person(age) VALUES(40);
INSERT INTO person(country) VALUES('Canada ');
```

When you should have done this:

```
INSERT INTO person(firstname,lastname,age,country) VALUES('john','smith',40,'canada');
```

Scrap that data (delete it all) and start over. Use one insert query per person, not per data item about a person

Answer (score 0):

You might find it more intuitive to use the alternative form of INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO person
SET firstname = 'Karen',
    lastname  = 'Whiting',
    address   = '1234 Street Name',
    city      = 'City Name',
    etc;
```

That inserts one row with a value in each respective column.